# 100% parent div with floated left images inside

Tags: css

I have a parent div that has a bunch of child divs inside it. I want the child divs to be horizontally laid out beside each other. Which means the parent div can not be set to an exact width amount as the image amount will change all the time. So I presumed setting the parent div to width:100% then the children div items inside it I would float:left.

It will only work if I give the parent div a set width that matches the width of all the child divs inside it. Is there a way to have it 100% and lay the children divs out side by side horizontally inside the parent.

Comment: So you don't want the children to wrap to two lines if the window is too small?

Comment: correct. They should display all in a horizontal row and the ones outside the browser window will still be in one line you just wont see them.

Comment: Wont see them at all or will there be a scrollbar

Comment: You can provide your code so far?

Comment: Can you post an example on http://jsfiddle.net?  What exactly "only works?"  What you are suggesting should work just fine..

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MmFVK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/k44Su/) - is this what you want?

Essentially, you just need to declare the following on your wrapper div, thats all

```
#wrapper{
 white-space:nowrap;  
 overflow:hidden; /* whatever suits you - could be scroll as well*/
}
```

you don't need to float the images, as they are no block-level elements per default.

Comment: Thanks Christoph but your example for me on FF is not showing the images sitting horizontally in a row. They seem to be wrapping to the next line.

Comment: FF has a problem with the empty src attribute. I tweaked the fiddle, try it again now.

Comment: Ok great I'm going to try and see why mine is not working. Its a little difficult to break all the code down and post it on here. If I can't get it to work from your example I will try and break mine down into a working example.